# Strip label customization in facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I want to shift the strip label of the facet graph in Col-2 to the right side.
As i marked in the graph,
[image]

I am using this code

```
library(reshape2)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggh4x)
library(scales)
library(ggplot2)
#step 1: mutate the data
df <- melt(df, id=c("Specie","Treatment"))
head(df)
#plotting
left  <- scale_y_continuous(labels = number_format(accuracy = 0.01))
right <- scale_y_continuous(labels = number_format(accuracy = 0.01),position = "right")

ggplot(df1, aes(x = Specie, y = mean, fill = Treatment, colour=Treatment)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge(), width = 0.8)+
  facet_wrap(~ variable, scales = "free_y", ncol = 2, 
             labeller = label_parsed, strip.position = "left")+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean, ymax = mean + sd), width = 0.2,
                position = position_dodge(0.9)) +theme_bw()+
  geom_text(aes(y = mean+sd,label = label),position = position_dodge(0.9),
            size = 3.5, vjust=-0.2, family="serif", colour="black")+
  geom_text(aes(y = Q1/2,label = letter),size = 3.5, family="serif", colour="#000000")+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c('#DEB887','#CD853F'))+
  scale_color_manual(values=c('#DEB887','#CD853F'))+
  facetted_pos_scales(y = list(left, right, left, right, left, right))+
  #coord_flip()+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(face = "italic"),
        strip.placement = "outside",
        strip.background = element_blank())
```

Here is the example dataset

| Treatment | Specie | Pn | Gs | E | WUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CT | S. commersonii | 4.8100 | 0.0736 | 1.1100 | 4.3333 |
| CT | S. commersonii | 11.5000 | 0.4660 | 5.4400 | 2.1140 |
| CT | S. tuberosum 2x | 16.4000 | 0.4930 | 5.5200 | 2.9710 |
| CT | S. tuberosum 2x | 4.2400 | 0.0862 | 1.8100 | 2.3425 |
| CT | S. chacoense | 3.9200 | 0.0426 | 0.7160 | 5.4749 |
| CT | S. chacoense | 7.9000 | 0.1500 | 1.9400 | 4.0722 |
| HS | S. commersonii | 10.1000 | 0.3520 | 6.0300 | 1.6750 |
| HS | S. commersonii | 6.8500 | 0.3700 | 5.4600 | 1.2546 |
| HS | S. tuberosum 2x | 4.7100 | 0.0205 | 0.8400 | 5.6071 |
| HS | S. tuberosum 2x | 4.3400 | 0.0314 | 1.2450 | 3.4859 |
| HS | S. chacoense | 13.8000 | 0.2450 | 6.4800 | 2.1296 |
| HS | S. chacoense | 14.4000 | 0.1700 | 5.5100 | 2.6134 |

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Should we assume facetted_pos_scales is from ggh4x?

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks for the advice; I have added more information.

Comment: @JonSpring Yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `patchwork` package and piece together two plots, making the labels be individual then patched together with a shared axis/legend. This doesn't include all the specifications in your plot (e.g., error bars, colors, text), but the general idea is:

```
library(patchwork)


#Creating dataset and adding grouping variable
mod_iris <- iris %>% 
    group_by(Species) %>% 
    mutate(average_petal_length = mean(Petal.Length)) %>% 
    mutate(species_length_group = case_when(Petal.Length <= average_petal_length ~ "Short",
                                            TRUE ~ "Long")) %>% 
    select(-average_petal_length) %>% 
    ungroup() %>% 
    pivot_longer(cols = "Sepal.Length":"Petal.Width")  

#Create two datasets

#One for length

iris_lengths_data <- mod_iris %>% 
    filter(!str_detect(name,"Width"))

#This will be plot that has information on the left
length_plot <- iris_lengths_data %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = Species, y = value, fill = species_length_group, color = species_length_group)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
    facet_wrap(.~name, scales = "free_y", ncol = 1, strip.position = "left") +
    theme(strip.placement = "outside")



#One for width

iris_widths_data <- mod_iris %>% 
    filter(str_detect(name,"Width"))
    
#This will be plot that has information on the right
width_plot <- iris_widths_data %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = Species, y = value, fill = species_length_group, color = species_length_group)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
    facet_wrap(.~name, scales = "free_y", ncol = 1, strip.position = "right") +
    scale_y_continuous(position = "right") +
    labs(y = NULL)+ #Removed to have just one y axis
    theme(strip.placement = "outside",
          strip.text.y.right = element_text(angle = 90))  #adjusted to have text in same direction as length plot

    

#Patch together 
iris_patch <- length_plot + width_plot + plot_layout(guides = "collect") & xlab(NULL) & theme(legend.position = "right")


#Add common x-axis and position
wrap_elements(panel = iris_patch) +
    labs(tag = "Species") +
    theme(plot.tag = element_text(size = rel(1)),
          plot.tag.position = c(.415, 0))
```

[image]